# How to Clear Content - Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Everytime I open a Bootstrap Modal form, I want a fresh load of content instead of adding to existing form (default behavior). So I want `hello world` to show on the form once instead of keep appending them to each other. I looked up how to do this on here and tried all answers but none of them work for me. For example, `reset()` would clear the fields but not remove them, `removeData('bs.modal')` does not do anything, `.html('')` deletes the form entirely and not just the fields. I am in need of a method to accomplish what I want, to have new form everytime and load the content each time fresh.

Also hello world here is just an example, actual form fields could be many. So I do not want to create a new form in a function but rather clear it and just load certain contents.

JS

```
function closeForm() {
    $('#myform').removeData('bs.modal'); 
}

function loadForm() {
    $('#myform')[0].reset();

    var html = "<p>Hello world</p>";
    $("#myform").append(html);
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myformDiv" onclick="loadForm()">Open form</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myformDiv" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button onclick="closeForm()" type="button" class="close right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="close">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="myform">

                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events) provides the `show` and `hidden` events. You can clear your form on `hidden` and add content on `show`.

```js
$('#myformDiv').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
  var html = "<p>Hello world</p>";
  $("#myform").append(html);
});

$('#myformDiv').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myform').empty();
  console.log("modal closed and content cleared");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Code -->
<a href="#" class="right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myformDiv">Open form</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myformDiv" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="close">&times;</span>
                </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="myform">

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And just put `$('#myformDiv').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myform').empty();
  console.log("modal closed and content cleared");
});` in a script tag? They are never triggered for some reason

Comment: I am using v3.3.7 of Bootstrap too

Comment: @Stuwart did you remove the 'onClick' from your '<a>' and '<button>'? I'm on my phone now, I will take a look later when I have my laptop.

Comment: Yes it is removed from <a>, there is an onclick on my <button> which I did not include in this post, I wonder if that is the issue

Comment: @Stuwart do you have bootstrap js loaded in your code? Does my on show code work for you?

Comment: @Stuwart one more thing, you have to load bootstrap.js and jquery.js before this script tag in your dom. Do you see any exceptions in your browser console? Does the snippet in my answer works for you?

Comment: no exceptions in console and Bootstrap is loaded. The modal closes as expected but just that `on('hidden.bs.modal'` never executes  I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

an easy but not best way:

1-  create a div tag contains all your form fields.give it an id (for example "myFields")  and set `style="display:none"`

2- on modal  load  set  `$("#myform").html($("#myFields").html());`

Comment: How does this solve the problem of repetitively appending the same content

Comment: it creates  a clone of original empty form,  and replaces that with filled form.

Comment: I would prefer to not clone the original form